# Badges -- single vs multi-time awards

Tags: feature-request, badges

There are badges like `Analytical` ("Visited every section of the FAQ") which can be awarded to a person only once. Yet there are those that can be obtained multiple times, like `Nice question` ("Question score of 10 or more"). For some questions it is clear that they can be obtained only once (usually they have "First" in the description). For others it is impossible to know without either trying to actively fulfill the requirements for the badge twice, or checking the profiles of other users (for example `Suffrage`, "Used 30 votes in a day").

I believe this to be flawed UX. The badge itself must bear an indication of whether it can be obtained once or multiple times. Maybe use a different background color, or make the badge title in italic or bold-face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Badges aren't that important, IMO, and if they added indicators for everything it would just be Too Much Information (and confusing). There's no real use of knowing if a badge can be awarded multiple times. If you really want more info about something, the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)  [on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) covers it.

Also, as @Laura says below, clicking on the badge takes you to a page where you can see if it can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Just a note: if you look at the [/badges](http://ux.stackexchange.com/badges) page of any site, you can click an individual badge name to see whether it can be awarded multiple times - [see the Famous Question page, for example](http://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/37/famous-question). I agree with you that adding indicators on the badges themselves would be TMI.

Comment: @Laura: Right, thanks :)